# Continuity of piecewise multivariable function

Tags: general-topology, continuity, epsilon-delta

Show that the function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by

$g(x_1,x_2)= \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0 &  x_1^2+x_2^2<1\\
       1 &  \text{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.$

is continuous.

I'm not convinced that $g$ is continuous, because when $x_{a}^2+x_{b}^2<1$ and $x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2\geq1$, $d(g(x_a,x_b),g(x_1,x_2))=1$, which should be greater than $\varepsilon$ for some $0<\varepsilon<1$, and the definition of continuity requires it to be less than $\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon$.

Comment: $g$ is indeed not continuous.

Comment: You are right, there must be an error or a typo somewhere

Comment: as you suggested, if $z_n=(0,\tfrac{n-1}{n})$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(z_n)=0\neq 1=g(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the useful proof with sequences in the comments,here it is another topological proof.

> Let $f:(X,d_1) \to (Y,d_2)$  where $(X,d_1), (Y,d_2)$ are metric spaces.
>
> Then $f$ is continuous iff for every closed $V \subseteq Y$ the $f^{-1}(V)$ is a closed subset of $X$.

Now let $(X,d_1)=(\mathbb{R}^2,d_2)$ where $d_2$ is the Euclideian metric and   $(Y,d_2)=(\mathbb{R},|.|)$

and $f(x_1,x_2)= \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0 &  x_1^2+x_2^2<1\\
       1 &  \text{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.$

Take the set $\{0\}$ which is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Then $f^{-1}(\{0\})=B(0,1)$ where $B(0,1)$ is the unit ball which is not a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

So $f$ is not continuous.